# [Angular, Jersey]Why i have to specify the application name in $http using jersey

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, jersey

I wonder why i have to specify the name of my application when i call a $http. Each time i see an example on the web using jersey and angular they don't specify the application name.

This is i have to write to make it works:

```
$http({method: "POST", url: '/MyAppName/rest/service'})
```

This is i see on the web but it doesn't work for me:

```
$http({method: "POST", url: '/rest/service'})
```

My web.xml is common:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I don't want to specify the name of my application. So how to do?

Comment: So then wouldn't you just put the application in the root of whatever servlet container you are using? This doesn't seem to be a code question but a server configuration one.

Comment: Do you mean by specify <url-pattern>/MyAppName/rest/*</url-pattern> ? It doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your web app is deployed on a Tomcat or Jetty container. Since you can deploy a couple of application on such a container, each application's path can't be the root (/) of your server, but something relative to root - and in those application servers, it's the name of your app.

If your .war is installed as a web app under a certain name, all requests to that app's REST resources need to be relative to that webapp's name:

[image]

In that case, you have paths like

- /manager/
- /myWar/

The issue could be resolved by using an apache httpd in front of the application server which rewrites URLs, or one of many existing [rewrite filters](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) for Tomcat.

Another solution would be to deploy all your REST services into one .war named `rest` and the HTML and JS as static resources [and map the path to the static resources](http://www.kuligowski.pl/java/rest-style-urls-and-url-mapping-for-static-content-apache-tomcat,5) so you can adress them from the root url. Pesonally, I don't think separating java classes and the html is worth it, but that's your choice here.

Comment: Thank you. It is quite difficult for me to make these changes. I keep your response for later. If i keep my appName in URL and if i host my webapp on the web, i'll just have to change in my code (url attribute of $http) the URL given by the server right? (for example: "h ttp://newApp.com")

Comment: yes, exactly. BTW, do you use Tomcat or Jetty?. Oh and another idea: you could try `url: rest/service/...`, that should also work.

Comment: I use tomcat. Oh yeah rest/service works ! I thought i had try this syntax. So i'll use now rest/service. Thanks a lot